# dragging hyperlink and then typing new text includes new text in hyperlink

Tags: firefox, tinymce, tinymce-4

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/tinymce/test3.html

When I drag the "Sample Link" down to the textarea and then start typing the new text I type in is part of the hyperlink. Any ideas as to how I might go about changing this behavior? ie. so that newly typed in text is *not* part of the hyperlink?

This problem only seems to happen in Firefox and not Chrome. In Chrome nothing happens when I drag it.

Comment: On Chrome, when I drag the "Sample Link" to the textarea and then start typing, nothing happens because the textarea is not in focus. I must click within the textarea to be able to start typing, which will occur wherever I had clicked.

Comment: The problem I described happens in Firefox - not Chrome. I've updated my orig post. Thanks!

Comment: If you open a 100 rep bounty, I'll write a custom TinyMCE plugin that will address this issue for you.

Comment: Sure, why not? Although it'll need to work on my end before I award the bounty! But I do award bounties as evidenced by my possession of the Benefactor badge so you don't have to worry about that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/221/benefactor?userid=569976

Comment: Answered ;) And also upvoted, because this is an issue that the TinyMCE authors should have addressed long ago!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
(function($) {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.fixinsertlinks', {

        init : function(editor, url) {

            editor.on('keydown', function(event) {

                var ignoredKeys = [8,46,37,38,39,40,27,16,17,18,91,9,20,121,122,123];
                if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, ignoredKeys) == -1) {
                    var node = editor.selection.getNode();
                    var a = editor.dom.getParent(node, 'a');
                    var b = editor.dom.getParent(node, 'b');
                    var i = editor.dom.getParent(node, 'i');

                    var a_is_parent_of_b = editor.dom.getParent(b, 'a');
                    var a_is_parent_of_i = editor.dom.getParent(i, 'a');

                    var b_is_parent_of_i = editor.dom.getParent(i, 'b');
                    var i_is_parent_of_b = editor.dom.getParent(b, 'i');

                    var element = false;
                    if (a) {
                        element = a;
                        if (b && !a_is_parent_of_b) {
                            element = b;
                            if (i && i_is_parent_of_b) {
                                element = i;
                            }
                        }
                        if (i && !a_is_parent_of_i) {
                            element = i;
                            if (b && b_is_parent_of_i) {
                                element = b;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (b) {
                        element = b;
                        if (i && i_is_parent_of_b) {
                            element = i;
                        }
                    } else if (i) {
                        element = i;
                        if (b && b_is_parent_of_i) {
                            element = b;
                        }
                    }

                    if (element) {
                        var $caretPlaceholder = $('<span id="caret_placeholder">&nbsp;</span>');
                        editor.dom.insertAfter($caretPlaceholder, element); 
                        editor.selection.select(editor.dom.select('span#caret_placeholder')[0]);
                        editor.dom.remove(editor.dom.select('span#caret_placeholder')[0]);
                    }                   
                }
            });

        },  

        getInfo: function() {
            return {
                longname : 'Move cursor outside of links',
                author : 'Me',
                authorurl : 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700597/dragging-hyperlink-and-then-typing-new-text-includes-new-text-in-hyperlink',
                infourl : '',
                version : "2.0"
            };
        }
    });

    tinymce.PluginManager.add('fixinsertlinks', tinymce.plugins.fixinsertlinks);

})(jQuery);
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Ugeaab/2

Try to drag any link from the left sidebar (e.g. the "feedback" link from the bottom), you can now very easily add your own text after the link that is not part of the link.

This plugin fixes the issue on any browser. To edit the text of the link, just click the link button in the toolbar.

Cheers!

Edited:

To use this plugin, make sure to include the above javascript anywhere in your page (even in a separate file), and add it to the list of plugins (its name is `fixinsertlinks`) upon initializing TinyMCE. Refer to the example fiddle for further details on initializing TinyMCE with custom plugins.

Comment: When I try to award bounty it says "You may award your bounty in 22 hours". I'll try again tomorrow evening.

Comment: Adding `<b>` tags causes it to sorta break. I've updated http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/tinymce/test4.html to demonstrate. The anchor tag is still terminated but the bold tag is retained after dragging. Seems like it ought to close all tags when the link is dragged - not just close some of them.

Comment: So it seems like it works if the `<b>` tag is within the `<a>` tag. If the `<a>` is within the `<b>` tag it doesn't work. I tried replacing `editor.dom.getParent(node, 'a')` in your code with `editor.dom.getParent(node)` but that didn't really work so well either. After typing in 2-3 keys it started prepending all the keys I entered to the beginning of the text instead of the end. Any ideas? I'll award the bounty if this remaining issue can be resolved. Thanks!

Comment: @neubert I've updated the answer. Any combination if `a`, `b` and `i` will work: `<a><b></b></a>`, `<b><a></a></b>`, `<a><i></i></a>`, `<i><a></a></i>`, `<i><b><a></a></b></i>`. Cheers!

Comment: what if the tag you want to do is <strong>? seems that an optimal solution wouldn't require every possible permutation of parents be delineated as yours seems to be doing.

Comment: @tiffanyvuitton what solution are you suggesting? There is no drag&drop event in TinyMCE, so we can't filter out the dragged&dropped content. If the tag you want to do is either `<strong>` or `<em>` then you have a problem as you will not be able to write within those tags which are used by TinyMCE for bold and italic styling. I agree that my solution isn't optimal, but please suggest a better way that is technically possible and I'll be pleased to implement it.